# IOS - Loading assets from an external stripped SWF

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air

I have a flash (AIR) application for IOS.

I package the app using adt (Air Developer Tool), while passing a list of SWFs that I intend to load externally later to be stripped of code, for the sake of argument let's say there's only one SWF I need to strip of code.

The app is packaged successfully, and a SWF that is stripped from code is created into the folder "externalStrippedSwfs".

I run the app on IOS and load from my server at runtime the stripped SWF that was created by adt.
That stripped SWF contains assets (e.g. textures) that were embedded using embed tags in ActionScript 3.

When the SWF's loading is complete, no definitions exist in the application domain for some reason.

I'd like to point out that when I test this on PC everything works as it should (of course loading a SWF that is not stripped of code in that case).

Here're two different loading approaches I tried for loading the external stripped SWF, both load the SWF successfully, but both result in an empty vector of definition names on IOS.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeka4xo52clhhak/LoaderA.as?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl06foy95mt63lg/LoaderB.as?dl=0

Naturally, when I try to get an asset an error is returned because no definitions exist:

```
try
{
    trace(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition("something"));
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Error: " + error.name + ", " + error.errorID + ", " + error.message);
}
```

Comment: In the original non-stripped asset SWF, if I have an asset class that has an embedded resource and than `strip` it, the asset class is now included in the packaged SWF (and thus IPA) and the embedded resource/asset is in the stripped SWF, once that stripped SWF is locally or remotely loaded, a `getDefinitionByName` of that asset class will now work as if the original asset SWF was loaded.

Comment: Yes it should work, however like I mentioned this weird problem occurs on IOS. Do you perhaps have any specific insight about the code?

Comment: I've used the boiler-plate code from Adobe, must people tend to 'forget' to add the exteranSWFs tags (<externalSwfs>assets/assestSWF.txt</externalSwfs>) to the xxx-app.xml or forget that the assets dir(s) that the asset SWfs are in and processed by  `adt` have to match the `externalSwfs` tags...

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop's mobile template. I didn't forget these actually. I'm specifying in the XML a text file which contains the list of external SWFs.

Comment: Do not load your assets that way period. You are only doing that in the name of some misplaced laziness that has no place in mobile development. Put your assets in a folder then load them and forget about loading swfs.

Comment: It's the complete opposite of laziness, I'm doing that for a unified solution for loading assets on both mobile and web. I can resort to loading the assets from a folder at any point, that's very easy to do.